# Substitute field name in a NSPredicate template

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I am in need of building a dynamic NSPredicates. I found very convenient to use a string file where I can apply a substitution variable. This is what I did in the file.

```
start<=$START AND end>=$END
```

and this is the code fragment which resides in a utility method:

```
-(NSPredicate*)predicateWithName:(NSString*)name andVariables:(NSDictionary*)dict { 
    NSURL *queryFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:name withExtension:@"query"];
    //... 
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:queryFile encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:&err];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:query];
    return [predicate predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:dict];
}
```

it all works very well, but now I am in need of adding a dynamic field, based on some condition I would like to query a specific field, but I cannot find a way to accomplish this. The query file could become:

```
start<=$START AND end>=$END AND $FIELD_NAME==1
```

$FIELD_NAME name get substituted with quotation marks and the query does not work. I know I could use %K for a key, but seems there's no way to do this with dictionary.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, there's no built-in way that I know of to do this.  However, it's pretty simple to write yourself.  You could easily write an `NSPredicate` category method that replaces variables that start with `KEY_` with a key path expression, like this:

```
- (NSPredicate *)predicateWithEnhancedSubstitutionVariables:(NSDictionary *)vars {
  if ([self isKindOfClass:[NSCompoundPredicate class]]) {
    // recurse for compound predicates
    NSCompoundPredicate *compound = (NSCompoundPredicate *)self;
    NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSPredicate *subpredicate in [compound subpredicates]) {
      NSPredicate *new = [subpredicate predicateWithEnhancedSubstitutionVariables:vars];
      [subpredicates addObject:new];
    }
    return [[[NSCompoundPredicate alloc] initWithType:[compound compoundPredicateType] 
                                        subpredicates:subpredicates] autorelease];
  } else {
    NSPredicate *final = self;
    // on comparison predicates, pull out the left and right expressions
    NSComparisonPredicate *comparison = (NSComparisonPredicate *)self;
    NSExpression *left = [comparison leftExpression];

    // substitute, if appropriate
    if ([left expressionType] == NSVariableExpressionType) {
      NSString *variable = [left variable];
      if ([variable hasPrefix:@"KEY_"]) {
        NSString *replacement = [vars objectForKey:variable];
        if (replacement) {
          left = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:replacement];
        }
      }
    }

    // substitute, if appropriate
    NSExpression *right = [comparison rightExpression];
    if ([right expressionType] == NSVariableExpressionType) {
      NSString *variable = [right variable];
      if ([variable hasPrefix:@"KEY_"]) {
        NSString *replacement = [vars objectForKey:variable];
        if (replacement) {
          right = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:replacement];
        }
      }
    }

    // build and return the appropriate comparison predicate
    if (left != [comparison leftExpression] || right != [comparison rightExpression]) {
      if ([comparison customSelector] != NULL) {
        final = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:left 
                                                   rightExpression:right 
                                                    customSelector:[comparison customSelector]];
      } else {
        final = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:left 
                                                   rightExpression:right 
                                                          modifier:[comparison comparisonPredicateModifier] 
                                                              type:[comparison predicateOperatorType] 
                                                           options:[comparison options]];
      }
    }
    return [final predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:vars];
  }
}
```

With this, you should be able to do:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"$KEY_DATE = $DATE"];
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"myDateProperty", @"KEY_DATE", aDate, @"date", nil];

p = [p predicateWithEnhancedSubstitutionVariables:d];
```

And get back a predicate as if you had done:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"myDateProperty = %@", aDate];
```

<sub>warning: typed in a browser, not compiled, yadda yadda</sub>